# white regions in heatmap by R

Tags: r, heatmap

There is a strange problem in my heatmap plot, it has the white region, but I never specified white color.

```
# cluster.in.da is my data
cluster.in.da <- t(scale(t(cluster.in.da)))
quantile.range <- quantile(cluster.in.da, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
palette.breaks <- seq(quantile.range["5%"], quantile.range["95%"], 0.01)
color.palette  <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "black", "blue"))(length(palette.breaks) - 1)
heatmap(cluster.in.da,scale="none",breaks=palette.breaks,col=color.palette)
```

What does the white regions mean?  I think it has something to do with my data, what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: @KonradRudolph More likely to be the `quantile.range` used to define the `colour.palette` I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely because you set breaks from the 5-95% quantile limits. R doesn't know what colour to assign values outside this range. Example...

```
#No NA's in the data
m <- matrix( rnorm(100) , nrow = 10 )
quantile.range <- quantile( m , probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01) )
palette.all <- seq( quantile.range["0%"], quantile.range["100%"], 0.01 )
palette.half <- seq( quantile.range["50%"], quantile.range["100%"], 0.01 )


color.palette  <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "black", "blue"))(length(palette.all) -1)
h.all( m , scale="none",breaks=palette.all,col=color.palette)
```

[image]

```
color.palette  <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "black", "blue"))(length(palette.half) -1)
h.all( m , scale="none",breaks=palette.half,col=color.palette)
```

[image]

Comment: You are right @SimonO101. Default heatmap doesnt know how to know this. I used the "heatmap.2" (gplots), it works, the value beyond the range are take as the same as the range value.